# DataGridView C# Help Required

Tags: c#, datagridview

This is my configuration for DataGridView.

```
 MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(Declare.connectionString);
 mysqlCon.Open();
 MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();         
 MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, mysqlCon);
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 MyDA.Fill(table);
 BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
 bSource.DataSource = table;
 dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
```

This works fine but i gotta use datagridview in many forms.
Do I need to write this Configuration again and again.
How do you configure it once and use it many times.
Please Help
Thanks

Comment: Add a class and define configurations once then make a function that accepts a sql query and returns a datatable. where ever you want to use datagridview call that class function with your required query and show them into DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own user control and use that in multiple forms. This way, all the common code will reside in a single location. Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx) link to understand creating user controls in Windows forms.

Comment: But i will definitely change the table.
Different forms will have data from different table.

Comment: Your user control can expose the property that will allow consuming forms to set the datasource for the grid.

Comment: Dude,any other way ? This seems buggy.

Comment: What do you mean buggy?

Comment: Buggy for me.
I am a beginner.

Comment: Post the code you have and specific problems. If there are bugs, debug and figure out. There is a code review section somewhere on this site use that.